# Setting in Xcode to check values when I archive

Tags: xcode

My app has a variable pMode which I use to indicate whether or not I am testing. "T" is testing and "P" is production.

Just built the app the other day for Production, but didn't set pMode to P, so had problems.

Is there some way I set my build properties in Xcode to either alert me to check for this before I continue if I am Archiving or to check the code and see if this is set to P if I am Archiving?

Comment: How about you use #ifdef DEBUG check if you're in the debug configuration

Answer (score 0):

I would set this via a constant and conditionally compile the code:

```
#if TESTING
    doSomethingElse();
#endif
```

and set it via an Xcode Configuration file (`.xcconfig`):

```
TESTING=1
```

You can then specify a specific Xcode configuration file to use during for Archiving:

```
TESTING=0
```

You can specify a different Xcode configuration file on a per-build-configuration basis, so you'd need to duplicate the `Release` build configuration to `Archive` and also set the Archiving action within the Scheme to use the Archive build configuration.

[More about this from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-project_editor/articles/basingbuildconfigurationsonconfigurationfiles.html).